# Allow Typescript to understand which keys on an object were passed into function

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure this is possible so any ideas would be appreciated. Rather than trying to explain it I think the easiest way is with an example..

```js
interface Queries {
    foo?: string;
    boo?: string;
    bar?: string;
}

const go = async (arg1: Queries): DynamicReturnType => {
    // Is it possible in the return type of the function to only specify the keys that were passed in ie: { foo: string; bar: string })
   return arg1;
}

const result = go({
    foo: "fooooo",
    bar: "baaaaarr"
}); // Ideally the type for 'result' would be { foo: string; bar: string; }
```

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ3JYm)?  I'm confused about the `async` and `Promise` bit of this; you expect `result()` to be of type `{foo: string, bar: string}` but it's going to be a `Promise<{foo: string, bar: string}>`.  The async part of this seems to be beside the point of the question; could you remove it or clarify?

Comment: Sorry, Should have stuck await in front of it. I only added the promise bit in in order to show a return type for the function, it's irrelevant really

Comment: That's perfect, thanks - if you want to paste it as the answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want `go()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of its argument.  So `arg1` should not be of specific type `Queries`, but of some generic type `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Queries`.  Like this:

```
const go = <T extends Queries>(arg1: T): T => {    
    return arg1;
}
```

And that gives you the desired behavior:

```
const result = go({
    foo: "fooooo",
    bar: "baaaaarr"
});
/* const result: {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFdrAgZ2QbwChkTkYB7cgfgC5kcwpQBzAbmNICNLb7GX2pZJzhReDJiDaEAvoUIJyIBsmblkAXmQAeACrIIAD0ggAJngxZcAPgAUo5gEY6ugJQvN1gkI4koEMHQoEGQHR3Y5BSUVfxx0ABswTVVyWyIhCnI6ACJMynJsgBpfYVEckThK0Shs2Vd2AHoAKmRFZSTYhLA6dNJMugkBEpEoAf4pCOQmhqA)